# How to block tags programmatically on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I block certain tags for my custom post types programmatically using wordpress?

I know about the if ( current_user_can() ) function, but I'm not sure what to put in the curly braces to actually block a certain user role from accessing all elements of that tag.

Comment: When you register your post type you can define what capabilities are required to let users perform certain actions with your custom post types. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#capability_type However I would recommend using the members plugin here: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/members/ as it makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to block it for tags? I realized I need to specifically block by tag, not just custom post type. I've edited my post. I'm trying to refrain from using plugins.

Answer (score 1):

When you register your taxonomy set the `capabilites` argument to create custom capabilities for the different actions.

I would look something like this:

```
$args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'show_tagcloud'     => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => true,
        'capabilities'      => array(
            'manage_terms' => 'manage_my_tax',
            'edit_terms' => 'manage_my_tax',
            'delete_terms' => 'manage_my_tax',
            'assign_terms' => 'edit_my_tax',
        ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy-slug', array( 'post' ), $args );
```

In the above I've set the capabilities based on the default capabilities that are assigned by WordPress which are:

```
'manage_terms' => 'manage_categories'
'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories'
'delete_terms' => 'manage_categories'
'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'
```

After you have created the custom capabilities use the [Members plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/members/) to assign which roles can perform those capabilities.

Once the plugin is installed go to **Users > Roles**. Select the role you want to control and then go **Taxonomies** and set the capabilities for that role.